# Создать полоску клеток вверху сайта

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать полоску клеток вверху сайта? Я пытаюсь делать таким кодом

```css
header {
  background: linear-gradient( #bbb, transparent 1px), linear-gradient( 90deg, #bbb, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Но тогда остаются зазоры по бокам. Как можно сделать, чтобы клетка прижималась к верхнему и боковым краям без зазора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для body надо сбросить margin,

```
body {
  margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А если просто добавить бордер?:

```css
header {
  background: linear-gradient( #bbb, transparent 1px), linear-gradient( 90deg, #bbb, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
div {
  background: linear-gradient( #bbb, transparent 1px), linear-gradient( 90deg, #bbb, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  height: 90px;
  border-right:1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<br>
<div></div>
```